Was Star Trek the first TV series or even movie that dealt with the great distances between galaxies?
In multiple episodes the incredible distance between The Milky Way and Andromeda is dealt with fairly accurately or at least consistently: even at highest warp the 2 million light years that separate the two galaxies mean that it would take many lifetimes to reach it. (This is in "By Any Other Name" -- even with Kelvan modifications, the ship will still take centuries to reach Andromeda.)
I am not sure about Lost in Space or Outer Limits in this respect -- but both of these shows tended to play loose with speed and distances.
Later shows, like Stargate, nod to intergalactic distances but allow such travel using wormholes or indeed Stargate's.
Was Star Trek the first TV series or even movie that dealt with the great distances between galaxies?

Note that Star Gate requires specially-significant levels of power for intergalactic gates, such that they are only used very occasionally. Otherwise the distance between galaxies is still an obstacle for the FTL ships, though they did get it down to ~a month to fly between the Milky Way and Andromeda with sufficient drive power.

@OrangeDog Pegasus certainly? I don't remember Star Gate having any episodes in Andromeda.

@EikePierstorff yes, my mistake. Both Andromeda and Atlantis start with an A.

I don't see why intergalactic distances would ever need to be dealt with. It seems to me that the Milky Way is big enough for almost any story you'd want to tell in a TV series or even a movie.

@user14111 well, if you wanted to make a movie about traveling a huge star-less void it would be a good fit. Our if the fictitious universe already has FTL travel and you need to come up with a new border to conquer for your heroes. Frankly, you wouldn't even need the Milky Way, most of Star Trek would work as soap opera in someone's living room. It's just a bit of window dressing that makes the conflicts displayed on screen more fun to watch.

Are you only looking for TV and movies? Cause the Lensmen book series features travel between two galaxies, both by ships and even entire planets.

@OrangeDog stargate the movie had Abydos in another galaxy on the opposite side of the Universe. Which sounds impressive but is a bit overkill.

@user14111 well, because to have a galactic society you have to have easy interstellar travel. Then if you want a final frontier to overcome, it's intergalactic travel.

@VBartilucci: I am not surprised by some novel or short story addressing galactic distance which is why I asked about only TV and movies. On the other hand, as I understand it, the entire universe until about 100 years ago was thought to be our galaxy (I could be wrong) and so the very first novel to take into account other galaxies would indeed be interesting.
